# Inside js create a dynamic select

Tags: javascript, php

In the form I have the option to add dynamic fields.

One of the fields is a select, and I want it to be filled dynamically with a query to the database.

I'm trying this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 100;
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var length = wrapper.find("input:text").length;
    $.getJSON('artigo1.php', function (data) {
    if (x < max_fields) { 
      x++; 

      $(wrapper).append('<div id="teste"><div class="form-group col-md-4"><select class="form-control1" name="Ref[]" id="Reff"><option></option></select><span class="form-highlight"></span><span class="form-bar"></span><label class="label1" for="Ref">Referência</label></div><button class="remove_field" style="background-color: #313348;"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>');
    
    }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        Id = data[i][0];
        artigo = data[i][1];
        
        $("#Reff").html("");
    $("#Reff").append(artigo);                  

    }
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
$sql= $conn->prepare("SELECT Id, Artigo FROM dados.Produto ORDER BY Artigo ASC");
    $sql->execute(); 
    $qr = $sql->get_result();
    while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
        $DataDia[]='<option value="'.$ln['Artigo'].'">'.$ln['Artigo'].'</option>';

    }
    echo json_encode($DataDia);
```

But in this way the select is always empty.

**I'm also trying this way:**

```
var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var length = wrapper.find("input:text").length;
    $.getJSON('artigo1.php', function (data) {
    if (x < max_fields) { 
      x++;

      $(wrapper).append(`<div id="teste"><div class="form-group col-md-4"><select class="form-control1" name="Ref[]" id="Reff"><option></option>`);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          artigo = data[i][1];
        
          $(wrapper).append(`<option value="${ artigo }">${ artigo }</option>`);
          }
      $(wrapper).append(`</select><span class="form-highlight"></span><span class="form-bar"></span><label class="label1" for="Ref">Referência</label></div><button class="remove_field" style="background-color: #313348;"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>`);
    }
  
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Id, Artigo FROM dados.Produto ORDER BY Artigo ASC");

$stmt->execute();

$json = [];
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);

    $json[]= [(string)$Id, (string)$Artigo];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Here it returns the data from the database, but puts it out of select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let below is your select field where you want to push the options:

```
<!-- Consider this as the select field -->
<select id="myselect"></select>
```

Inject it at your script as the Ajax Function:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "artigo1.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(result){
            var html = `<option value="">Select any option</option>`;

            result.forEach(element => {
                html += `<option value="`+element.id+`">`+element.name+`</option>`;
            });

            $('#myselect').html(html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can help in this [question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64895176/loop-when-loading-a-select-in-js)  that is related to this