# Create fields dynamically in js

Tags: javascript, html

I create dynamic inputs and selects in js by clicking the button.
To fill in the select, I query a table in the database. The problem I have is that whenever I click the button to create a new input and select, it clears the previous select and shouldn't.

Code:

```js
var cars = [
   {colour: "red", },
   {colour: "white", },
   {colour: "black", },
];

var campos_max = 10; 

var x = 0;
$('#add_field').click (function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 

 if (x < campos_max) {
    $('#listas').append('<select class="form-control1 Reff" name="Ref[]"></select>');
 
}

var html = $('.Reff').html("");

cars.forEach(element => {
  html += `<option value="`+element.colour+`">`+element.colour+`</option>`;
    });
    
    $('.Reff').html(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listas"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-warning caixa"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>
```

I intended that when clicking the button to create a new select and input, do not delete the value that I already placed in the previous select.

The problem is that it always queries the database and then returns the data back to the previous select, but I don't know how to solve it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The snippet does not run. There is a syntax error on line 91.

Comment: @Abrar Hossain I already fixed the error

Comment: It doesn't do much because it has PHP in the middle of the HTML, which of course doesn't run in the snippet.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `.html(html)` which replaces all HTML in the element with the specified HTML. If you want it additive, add to the existing HTML, like `var html = $('.Reff').html();`.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I don't know if I understood what I meant, I put the code like this: `success: function(result){ result.forEach(element => { html += `<option value="`+element+`">`+element+`</option>`; }); var html = $('.Reff').html(html); }. 
But the same is true. If you put this line like this: `var html = $('.Reff').html();` 
Does not return data for select.

Comment: Replace where it says `var html = \`<option value=""></option>\`;` with `var html = $('.Reff').html();`. Don't add `var html = ` before the `$('.Reff').html(html);`. Think about what the code is doing. `var html = $('.Reff').html();` gets the current HTML from  the select. You add options to it. Then `$('.Reff').html(html);` adds the current HTML and the added options to the select.

Comment: I put in the question an example with the problem I have